# Databricks use AWS RDS without JDBC/ODBC

Tags: amazon-web-services, databricks, amazon-rds

I am trying to run query statements on databricks fetching an RDS instance as the source database.

I have done it already in the databricks python notebook using jdbc. And then using

```
#I first set my jdbc url and retrieve USER/PASSWORD. For obvious reason, I cannot show this part


query= 'SELECT * FROM transactions'

spark_df=spark.read.format('jdbc')\
    .option("url", jdbc_url) \
    .option("query", query) \
    .option("user", USER) \
    .option("password", PASSWORD)\
    .load()
```

Is there a way I can query the database directly without having to use jdbc? For example, there are platforms such as Mode analytics, Redash, Superset and more, where you just add your connection details in an admin view (host/port/user/password/etc) and then on a query editor you can just write plain SQL, and it's going straight to your RDS without having to do a jdbc connection for every query you do. It's almost as if you are using PGADMIN on the RDS instance.

So I am wondering if databricks can do the same, where it prompts just a sql editor and you can select your RDS tables. I know databricks has a SQL datawarehouse, but you have to create new instances of it and migrate data as far as I know. Is there not a way to just point towards an already existing RDS instance instead of creating a warehouse at databricks UI and migrate data?

For the research I have done, it all points towards creating a new warehouse from databricks, I see no documentation to add an existing RDS as your warehouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still JDBC under the hood, but you can create a [JDBC-based temporary view](https://docs.databricks.com/en/external-data/jdbc.html#read-data-with-jdbc) or [federated table](https://docs.databricks.com/en/query-federation/mysql-no-uc.html):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW rds_table
USING JDBC
OPTIONS (
  url "<jdbc-url>",
  dbtable "<table-name>",
  user '<username>',
  password '<password>'
);

-- or --

CREATE TABLE rds_table
USING mysql
OPTIONS (
  dbtable '<table-name>',
  host '<database-host-url>',
  port '3306',
  database '<database-name>',
  user secret('mysql_creds', 'my_username'),
  password secret('mysql_creds', 'my_password')
);
```

And then use it directly in the queries:

```
SELECT * FROM rds_table;
```

Alternatively, if using Unity Catalog, [Lakehouse Federation](https://Lakehouse%20Federation) allows you to mount entire foreign catalog representing your RDS instance - check docs for configuration details.